# In tensorflow,does embedding matrix remain unchanged?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

In tensorflow,we may see these codes.

*embeddings=tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([vocabulary_size,embedding_size],-1.0,1.0))*

*embed=tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings,train_inputs)*

When tensorflow is training,does embedding matrix remain unchanged?

In a blog,it is said that embedding matrix can update.I wonder how does it work.Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embedding matrix is similar to any other variable. If you set the trainable flag to True it will train it (see tf.Variable)

Comment: I wonder that the result of training embedding matrix is similar to word2vec?What's the difference between training embedding matrix and skip-gram model?In my opinion,training embedding matrix may be over-fitting.Thank you for your help!